# Load Stripe check out page in an iframe

Tags: iframe, stripe-payments

In my web application, all I am trying is to load stripe check out page in an iframe. However it is not loading and throwing the below error.

'Stripe Checkout is not able to run in an iFrame. Please redirect to Checkout at the top level.'

Can anybody help here? Any possibility or work around for integrating stripe check out page inside iframe?

[stripe error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKxl7.png)

Answer (score 7):

Stripe Checkout is not supported in an iframe. It requires a full page redirect so you should not try to embed it in an iframe and instead redirect your customer to the Checkout page.

Comment: Can anyone provide any links or documentation from Stripe that confirms this? Thanks